# Asterisk AGI/Outgoing Directory Permissions on Mount

Tags: linux, asterisk, sshfs, agi

I have a little issue with setting up an external call automatically from asterisk an box.

**What I am Trying to Achieve:**

I have 2 linux box's and I want to sshfs mount one directory on say 10.100.100.1 to 10.100.100.208/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing (as the mount point)

the reason is the 10.100.100.1 address is a device called Webbrick Gateway a home automation device which can send AGI commands if necessary. but what I want to be able to do is get this to move the .call file to the outgoing directory on the Asterisk Server (var/spool/asterisk/outgoing) or on 10.100.100.1 (Webbrick Gateway) /mnt/call/.

**What I've tried:**

I have tried to sshfs mount to /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing. This seems fine but it actually takes the privileges off user asterisk and then asterisk will not look at this folder for outgoing call files. The Owner and Group are changed to root, as I assume are the same with all mount points.

**Solutions I can think of:**

1.: Tell asterisk to look somewhere else for call files.

2.: Tell asterisk to not get worried about permissions,

3.: mount keeping permissions intact

I do understand that the Webbrick Gateway is not a commonly known item but maybe someone with a better understanding of Asterisk might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk can't "not worry about permission", becuase linux core just not allow asterisk do file operation.

You need

1. mount folder with correct permission(as user asterisk) for example using this [articles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123215/sshfs-is-mounting-filesystems-as-another-user)
2. Start asterisk AFTER mount of partition. If asterisk started before mount, it will not see mounted folder.